# Opening a file- How to make a .txt file return a list of lists

Tags: python, file, list

Ok so I have this txt file that I need to open which looks like this when I use the
code below (except with actual newline indents, not the \n syntax and the '' equals a space);

```
"#####\n #   #\n ### #\n #X  #\n #####"
```

... and then convert this into a list of 
lists like this;

```
[['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
['#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'],
['#', '#', '#', ' ', '#'],
['#', 'X', ' ', ' ', '#'],
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

Here's my code, I'm able to print the normal txt file into Shell but I can't
figure out how to convert it like above with the list of lists.

```
def file_open (filename):
openfile = open(filename, 'rU') 
str1= openfile.read()           
openfile.close()                
print str1
```

Can anyone help on how to go about doing this?

Comment: is there a separator (like space-character) within the text?

Comment: let me get this: you have a file with some text in it, right? and you just want to split the text, like this: line by line and character by character?

Comment: Sorry there are separators in the text (I've edited the question now). Yes that's what I'm aiming for- though I would like to do it within the file_open function if possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the string `s`...:

```
>>> s = "#####\n #   #\n ### #\n #X  #\n #####"
```

You can split it by each new line to get:

```
>>> print s.split('\n')
['#####', ' #   #', ' ### #', ' #X  #', ' #####']
```

And further split that:

```
>>> print [list(i) for i in s.split('\n')]
[['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'], [' ', '#', ' ', ' ', ' ', '#'], [' ', '#', '#', '#', ' ', '#'], [' ', '#', 'X', ' ', ' ', '#'], [' ', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#']]
```

To get your list.

Comment: @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus OP hasn't really told us much

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the 'eval' function which evaluates any python code stored into a string:

```
alist = eval(str1)
```

Note: However take care to the fact that this is unsafe by nature (as the string may contain malicious python code). But maybe it is not your concern here.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is **much, much** safer than using `eval`